# What are the materials needed to beat the dungeon guardian in the pc version of Terraria?

Tags: terraria

I need help beating the dungeon guardian in terraria mobile I already have:

Dragon armor and legendary terra blade.

Comment: You have a conflict in your versions. The title says PC, but the text of the question says mobile.

Comment: Since damage will always be 1 (or 2 on a crit) and the dungeon guardian can kill you in 1 hit no matter what armour you have, a ranged weapon with high speed and crit chance modifiers is all you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The wiki does have a [guide](http://terraria.gamepedia.com/Guide:Dungeon_Guardian_strategies) for fighting the Dungeon Guardian. Most of the advice is about how to outrun it because it is nearly impossible to have enough defence to survive even a single hit. The wiki suggests choosing your armour for offensive effects rather than defensive. Thus frost, orichalcum or clorophyte armour, although if you are lucky and good, titanium armor gives temporary invincibility.

Due to the one hit kills you thing, ranged weapons are required. Fortunately the Terra Blade does count as a ranged weapon in this regard, if you just use the blade beam. However, since the Guardian's defence is so high, any hit will do only 1 damage, or 2 on a critical, so the high damage, relatively slow Terra Blade is not ideal. Choose something fast and or (preferably and) with lots of projectiles. For example, the vampire knives, or the mini/mega-shark with a splitting ammo (such as crystal ammo).

You will need a good arena though. The guide has several suggestions, including an asphalt skybridge and teleporters.

Good luck

Answer (score -1):

Easiest way is Excalibur the final sword of game
Only 3 second and use the turtle shell armor set too 
Because it is thorn 100% Like 
If you use any weapon and turtle armor set then
Use your weapons attack the dungeon gaurdian
And then Dungeon gaurdian touch you it will
Dies instantly be cause i told you it is thorn 100%
The bad thing is you need to go back to the dungeon and grab
The dropping stuff it drop bone key 100%

More tips - if you already kill the skeletron of dungeon
The dungeon gaurdian will gone forever and it will become
To avaible you to exploring full version of that dungeon

If you need to get new dungeon
Just create the new world

Dungeon gaurdian >>>>>>>>><100%Thorn|<<< You

.You will die and dungeon gaurdian is dies too

Comment: The exalabur was NOT the last sword in terraria.